# Count records with criteria

Tags: mysql, count, subquery, rdbms

I use the following query to count the total player entries per tournament on a list.

```
    SELECT fab_tournaments.tournament, count(fab_plist.id) AS cnt
    FROM fab_plist
    INNER JOIN fab_tournaments ON fab_tournaments.id = fab_plist.tournament
    WHERE fab_tournaments.activation = 'No'
    GROUP BY fab_plist.tournament
    ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

So far so good and displays correctly the total player entries per tournament.
The problem is that as the players are Men and Women I would like to count also in two different columns the total of the Men and the Women players per tournament.

I tried using subqueries but I get an error that the subquery return more than one rows.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please tag your question with the RDBMS you're using: MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MySQL, this will work.

```
SELECT fab_plist.tournament,
       SUM(fab_plist.gender = 'male') AS men,
       SUM(fab_plist.gender = 'female') AS women,
       COUNT(*) AS total
FROM fab_plist
INNER JOIN fab_tournaments ON fab_tournament.id = fab_plist.tournament
WHERE fab_tournament.activation = 'No'
GROUP BY fab_plist.tournament
```

If you're using some other database, you may have to change to

```
SUM(CASE WHEN fab_plist.gender = 'male' THEN 1 END) AS men
```

and similar for women.

Comment: Thanks for your answer which did the trick! Actually I was using the same query but instead of SUM I put COUNT for Men and Women..:-(